# Stopping a delay in pygame/python

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame to create something and I need to have a delay for about 10 seconds that is interrupted when a button is pushed. When I tried to do this, it paused on the delay and it was unable to detect for button pushes. I was wondering if this is even possible or if there are any alternatives. I have tried:

```
pygame.time.delay(10000)
if hit1: #hit1 is a bool representing keydown
    Blue1() #my function to draw a shape
```

Comment: Can you show your code? I'm not a shaman who easily guesses the error you get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I happened to have come across the same problem 2 years ago (when I was 12) so I think I understand what you mean.
First import sleep from time

```
from time import sleep
```

Then you can try this

```
#code before 10 sec count
interrupt = false
millisecondPassed = 0
while true:
    sleep(0.01)
    millisecondPassed += 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_b:
                interrupt = true
    if millisecondPassed >= 10000 or interrupt == true:
        break
#code after interruption
```

As for reference:
10 seconds = 10000 milliseconds